# How do I change this output array to make it compatible with my Pandas Graph?

Tags: python, sql, arrays, pandas, list

I'm currently working on a Python project to grab data from a Microsoft SQL Server database and then turn it into a graph view using Pandas, however it does not seem to work because of the array I am getting from the database.

```py
# Import Modules
import pandas as pd # Graph Module
import pyodbc # Microsoft SQL Server Module

# Connection string
conn_str = (
        "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
        "SERVER=server,port;"
        "DATABASE=db;"
        "UID=user;"
        "PWD=pass;"
)

conn  = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT processname AS 'Proces Naam' FROM table WHERE status = 'Aborted' ORDER BY processname ASC") 

result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

**Current Output:**

```py
[('proces1', ), ('proces2', ), ('proces3', ), ('proces4', ), ('proces5', ), ('proces6', ), ('proces7', )]
```

**Desired Output:**

```py
['proces1','proces2','proces3','proces4','proces5','proces6','proces7']
```

I'm trying to use this output for a pandas plot bar graph, and it currently doesn't work with the Current Output I've shown above. I have tried to use `result = cursor.fetchone()` instead and then it does work, of course only with one result rather than the entire list of results I need in the graph.

The output of the `result = cursor.fetchone()` looks like this;

```py
('proces1', )
```

Which is strange, because this output DOES work.

This right here is the code I use for the Pandas Graph:

```py
# Set Dataset
dataset={
        'PROCESS':[result],
        'ABORTS':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17] # just some random placeholder numbers. I know the result of the query is 17 rows of procesnames
}

# Create Graph
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
df.plot.bar(title="Aborts", x='PROCESS')
```

This is my current error code;

```py
    "name": "ValueError",
    "message": "arrays must all be same length",
```

Does anyone know a good way to clean up this array or maybe have a better understanding of Pandas and how to get this graph to work? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try: `result = [r[0] for r in result]` after `fetchall`?

Comment: Do you mean ```results = cursor.fetchall() result = [r[0] for r in result]``` or do you mean ```results = cursor.fetchall(result = [r[0] for r in result])```? I tried both ways that I just mentioned, however this did not work for me.

Comment: In your code, you have not the plural of `result`.

Comment: `result = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall()]`

Comment: This works, however I do not quite understand why it works or what it really does to make it work. Could you explain why this works or why you went for this option or maybe share some documentation for why this works?

Comment: When you use `fetchall`, you get a list of tuple of one element. I just extract the first and only element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Set Dataset
dataset={
        'PROCESS':[r[0] for r in result],
        'ABORTS': np.random.randint(1, 10, len(result))
}

# Create Graph
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
df.plot.bar(title="Aborts", x='PROCESS', rot=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: However, if you don't mind, I do have a second question, currently it only shows a G under my bars. Likely because all processes start with a G and are quite long names. Do you know of a way to make it so that even though the names are quite long it still displays them fully?

Comment: Also another question. You currently use numpy to generate a random number for the value of the Aborts. But when I tried to apply your first method of ```[i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]``` on my second query that retrieves the values for these processes I ended up with the error ```'int' object is not subscriptable```. Would you happen to have any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: If you have long names, you can truncate the process names. You can use `df['PROCESS'].str[:15]` to keep the first 15 characters.

Comment: What is your second query?

Comment: Thank you for the idea about truncating the names, this will help a lot :)

Comment: My second query is a count of all the procesnames and how many times they are going aborted. It looks like this: ```SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT Aborted' FROM db WHERE status = 'Aborted' GROUP BY processname ORDER BY processname ASC``` And because they are ordered by processname, just like the previous query, they should also correctly align with the output of the other query.

Comment: But what is the output of the query? I think you can just put the output as in to dataframe. I think you simply have a list of integers (and not a list of tuple of one integer) but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The output is just like the output of the other query ```[('1', ), ('2', ), ('3', ), ('4', ), ('5', ), ('6', ), ('7', )]```. However I just tried ```new_array = [ x for x in query2 if type(x)==int ]``` to extract the integers from the original array and store them in this new variable. Which changes the array to look like this: ```[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]``` and when using this new array in the graph it actually does work :)

Comment: `[ int(x[0]) for x in query2 if x[0].isdigit() ]`

Comment: I just tried the ```df['PROCESS'].str[:15]``` but it didn't do anything. I might've placed it somewhere wrong. I added it under```# Create graph df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset)
df['PROCESS'].str[:15]
df.plot.bar(title="Aborts Mario", x='PROCESS', rot=45)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()``` Did I place it wrong or should I have done something else?

Comment: Try `df.assign(PROCESS=df['PROCESS'].str[:15]).plot.bar(...)`

Comment: This also didn't work for me... maybe it's best that I try and this the name in the SQL query and hopefully that will fix the issue of not displaying the name of the processes... hopefully :)